# Problem reading Website content with a get request in java

Tags: java, eclipse

i'm trying to read the best price from the skyscanner website using a normal get request, but i'm not getting the content that i want by using this code.

```
private void getRequest() throws Exception {
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
    URL url = new URL(URL);
    HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    conn.addRequestProperty("User-Agent","Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:56.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/56.0");
    System.out.println(conn.getURL());
    conn.setInstanceFollowRedirects(true);
    HttpURLConnection.setFollowRedirects(true);
    conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
    BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
    String line;
    while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
        result.append(line);
    }
    System.out.println(conn.getURL());
    rd.close();
    response = result.toString();
}
```

The requested URL is the following:

```
https://www.skyscanner.com/transport/flights/fra/txl/181220/?adults=1&children=0&adultsv2=1&childrenv2=&infants=0&cabinclass=economy&rtn=0&preferdirects=false&outboundaltsenabled=false&inboundaltsenabled=false&currency=EUR&market=DE&locale=en-US
```

Response from the code above looks like this:

```
https://pastebin.com/YKh17RKE
```

By going to the mentioned skyscanner link in chrome i can click on inspect element and voila under

```
 fqs-opts-container -> <span class="fqs-price">42 €</span>
```

i can see the cheapest price.

How to get this information using java? What am i doing wrong here?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: _Inspect_ shows the current HTML DOM (Document Object Model) resulting from the static HTML page (_View page source_) plus dynamic modifications by JavaScript. If you go to _Inspect_, tab _Network_ and reload the page, you can see which files (and their contents) are all requested by the browser to display the page.

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply & the new information
I have been checking everything in the network section but i still don't have any idea that might help me to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

***Inspect*** shows the **current HTML DOM** (Document Object Model) resulting from:

- the **static HTML page** (see right-click + *View page source*) plus
- dynamic **modifications by JavaScript**.

If you do ***Inspect***, tab ***Network*** and **reload the page**, you can see which files (and their contents) are all requested by the browser to display the page.

In this particular case, it seems that you could get the data as JSON:

In the tab *Network* **filter for `conductor/v1/fps3/search/`**. The query is an **HTTP post request** with the URL `https://www.skyscanner.de/g/conductor/v1/fps3/search/?geo_schema=skyscanner&carrier_schema=skyscanner&response_include=query%3Bdeeplink%3Bsegment%3Bstats%3Bfqs%3Bpqs%3B_flights_availability`. The answer is in JSON and includes a `session_id` which is required as part of the URL for subsequent requests for details.

Please note that even if it is technically possible to receive the data, it is in most cases forbidden to use them commercially.

Comment: Thank you very much i will try this method.
I don't intend to use it commercially, i only want to learn how these things work and maybe just enough to build my own price alarm.